# Can we perform "Not null or return" in flutter with null safety feature?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to migrate null safety feature into my Flutter project because it's good for my future of project. Since I already have experience of developing Android app via Kotlin, I already got used to this null safety feature. But it seems I can't perform one thing which can be done in Kotlin.

```
user?.name ?? "Unknown"
```

I noticed that in Dart, I can set default value with this code line.
Now I'm trying to perform this

```
fun performOrReturn(users: Map<String, User>, id: String) {
    val user = users[id] ?: return //This line

    println("User info gotten : ${user.name}")
}
```

In Kotlin, I can perform this thing. I can make method return itself if specific variable is null, so Kotlin can handle null safety flexibly.

So here is what I'm trying to do, there is table in my code. I want to check if there is data existing in specified column and row in this field.

```
Map<int, List<MyData>> table = Map();

...

int _findDataExisting(int row, int col) {
    List<MyData> data = table[row]; //This is causing problem because table[row] can be null

    //Alternative solution is
    //List<MyData> data = table[row] ?? List.empty();
    //
    //if(data.isEmpty) {
    //    return -1;
    //}
    //

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i].column == col) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I want to make it return -1 rather than initializing default value because it's not good for handling memory, and code becomes inefficient.

```
List<MyData> data = map[row] ?? return -1;
```

I tried line below just like Kotlin, but Dart seems that it can't handle this.

Is there any equivalent thing in Dart? Making it return method if specific variable is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be fancy.

```dart
int _findDataExisting(int row, int col) {
  if (table[row] != null) {
    List<MyData> data = table[row]!;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i].column == col) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `table[row]` can be affected by multiple threads. If `table[row]` wasn't null when passing through if statement, and if it becomes null while performing for statement, it can cause error. Thus, Dart doesn't allow this. I guess I think I just have to use `List<MyData>?` instead, but I need someone to confirm that there is no way to perform thing I'm asking above.

Comment: @MandarinSmell Dart is a single-threaded language. It's literally impossible for the value of `table[row]` to change between the if-check and the for loop.

Comment: I tried your code, but it still prints error. Also, isn't `Future<>` actually multi-threading? I may be wrong because I'm learning Flutter/Dart yet

Comment: @MandarinSmell `Future` is asynchronous programming, which is not the same thing as multi-threaded (parallel) programming. Also, what error?

Comment: It still warns me that `table[row]` can be null even though I wrap my code with null checking if statement

Comment: Then coerce it into not being null by using `table[row]!`.

Comment: I would do that if I can perfectly sure that `table[row]` will never be null while performing this method. If Dart is run with single thread, and even asynchronous things like `Future` can't cause situation when `table[row]` becoming null, why is Android Studio warning me that `table[row]` can be null? If it's just because Flutter/Dart plugin in Android Studio isn't mature yet, then I will use `!` keyword

Comment: It's warning you that `table[row]` can be null because the indexer of a map is defined as returning a potentially nullable value. Logically you just checked that `table[row]` isn't null and since neither `table` nor `row` could possibly change between the check and the assignment (in this code, anyway), the coercion is guaranteed to not fail and so is technically redundant. The issue is just that the dart static analysis tool isn't robust enough to know this, so the coercion is still necessary.

Comment: I also hope it's just simply because of plugin. Okay, since I honestly didn't know Dart is run only with single thread, I will accept your way. Still, it will be really good if Dart team can add direct returning feature in future...

Answer (score 0):

You could initially declare `data` as *nullable* and let the null check automatically *promote* it to a non-nullable type, avoiding the need to use null assertions (`!`) later:

```dart
int _findDataExisting(int row, int col) {
  List<MyData>? data = table[row];
  if (data == null) return -1;  

  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].column == col) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```